# enforcing function's parameter must belongs to generic type T

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

In my typescript function I want to enforce all keys of second argument must belongs to object of first argument.

something similar to this

> mapTo([new KeyValue('a', 'b'), new KeyValue('x', 'y')],  {key: {key2: 1}});

in this all keys of second argument (**key** and **key2**) must belongs to keys of KeyValue object

here KeyValue is :

```
class KeyValue {
  key: string;
  key2: string;

  constructor(k, k2) {
    this.key = k;
    this.key2 = k2;
  }
}
```

like

> mapTo([new KeyValue('a', 'b')],  {key: {key2: 1}}); -> ok
>
> mapTo([new KeyValue('a', 'b')],  {key: {key3: 1}}); -> error // invalid key3

For this i have implemented mapTo function

```
public nest<T, K extends keyof T, K2 extends keyof T>(arr: [T], basis: {[k in K]: {[k2 in K2]}}) {
    console.log('Hello!!!');
    console.log(basis);
  }
```

this code work perfect but if I add another key in KeyValue class and pass this key in argument, like this:

> mapTo([new KeyValue('a', 'b' ,'c')],  {key: {key2: {key3: 1}}});

and KeyValue to :

```
class KeyValue {
  key: string;
  key2: string;
  key3: string;

  constructor(k, k2, k3) {
    this.key = k;
    this.key2 = k2; 
    this.key2 = k3;
  }
}
```

then my above implemented function would not validate third key

so how could i implement above function so that it accept dynamic nested values and work perfectly.

some more examples:

> mapTo([new KeyValue('a', 'b' ,'c')], {key: 1}); -> okay
>
> mapTo([new KeyValue('a', 'b' ,'c')], {key: {key1:1}}); -> okay
>
> mapTo([new KeyValue('a', 'b' ,'c')], {key1: {key:1}}); -> okay
>
> mapTo([new KeyValue('a', 'b' ,'c')], {key1: {key:{key3:1}}}); -> okay
>
> mapTo([new KeyValue('a', 'b' ,'c')], {key1: {key:{key4:1}}}); -> error // key4 not exist
>
> mapTo([new KeyValue('a', 'b' ,'c')], {key3: {key2:0}); -> okay

Comment: If there are 3 keys, does the caller have to specify a 3 level nested structure ? for your example is `{key : 1}` valid ? or does it have to be `{key : {key2 : {key3 : 0 }}`

Comment: not mandatory, but caller can call with 2 or 3 keys.
like:

`mapTo([new KeyValue('a', 'b' ,'c')], {key: 1}); -> okay

mapTo([new KeyValue('a', 'b' ,'c')], {key: {key1:1}}); -> okay

mapTo([new KeyValue('a', 'b' ,'c')], {key1: {key:1}}); -> okay

mapTo([new KeyValue('a', 'b' ,'c')], {key1: {key:{key3:1}}}); -> okay

mapTo([new KeyValue('a', 'b' ,'c')], {key1: {key:{key4:1}}}); -> error // key4 not exist`

Comment: I think your examples have an error .. where does `key1` come from  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive mapped type to define a structure that allows any key of `T` to be specified at each level. Also we can ensure that no key is specified twice in a path, by omitting the current key on each level using the `Omit` type:

```
type Diff<T extends string, U extends string> = ({ [P in T]: P } & { [P in U]: never } & { [x: string]: never })[T];
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Diff<keyof T, K>>;


type Nested<T> = { [P in keyof T]?: Nested<Omit<T, P>> | number }


function mapTo<T>(arr: [T], basis: Nested<T>) {
    console.log('Hello!!!');
    console.log(basis);
}
class KeyValue {
    constructor(public key: string, public key1: string, public key3: string) {
    }
}

mapTo([new KeyValue('a', 'b', 'c')], { key: 1 }); //-> okay 
mapTo([new KeyValue('a', 'b', 'c')], { key: { key1: 1 } }); //-> okay 
mapTo([new KeyValue('a', 'b', 'c')], { key1: { key: 1 } }); //-> okay 
mapTo([new KeyValue('a', 'b', 'c')], { key1: { key: { key3: 1 } } }); //-> okay
mapTo([new KeyValue('a', 'b', 'c')], { key1: { key: { key4: 1 } } }); //-> error // key4 not exist
mapTo([new KeyValue('a', 'b', 'c')], { key: { key: 1 } }); //-> error, key appears twice
```